# ¿Como puedo leer el contenido de un archivo CSV guardado el dispositivo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, csv

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que pueda leer un archivo CSV y almacene los valores en una matriz para después procesarlos (es importante que el usuario pueda escoger el archivo, por lo que debe estar almacenado en el dispositivo).

Mi problema es que recibo un error del tipo `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/HeartDisease.csv (No such file or directory)` aunque esa ruta si exista, aun así con el método `file.getName()` me devuelve **5049** y el `file.getAbsolutePath()` devuelve **/document/5049**

Tengo el siguiente bloque de código para seleccionar el archivo CSV

```java
    public void clickButton() {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, CHOOSE_FILE);
        } else {
            Intent getFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            getFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            getFile.setType("text/csv");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(getFile, "Open CSV"), CHOOSE_FILE);
        }
    }
```

Y la siguiente función para leerlo (por el momento no eh intentado guardar la información porque no lo eh podido leer el CSV)

```java
    private void importCSV(File file) {
        viewPath.setText(file.getAbsolutePath() + " is selected ");

        try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            String[] line;

            while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                viewInfo.setText(line[0]);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "We can\'t read this file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Por ultimo mando a llamar la función `importCSV` desde `onActivityResult`

```java
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CHOOSE_FILE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    importCSV(new File(data.getData().getEncodedPath()));
                    viewInfo.setText(data.getData().getLastPathSegment());
                }
        }
    }
```

Este es el log completo

```
12/21 20:51:11: Launching 'app' on motorola moto g(6) plus.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.clusterdroid/com.example.clusterdroid.Home" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 21383 on device 'motorola-moto_g_6__plus-ZY322NHN9G'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/le.clusterdroi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/le.clusterdroi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 9128d71, Ib33d3e8e13
    Build Date                       : 11/02/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.01
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
    Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/HeartDisease.csv (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
        at com.example.clusterdroid.Home.importCSV(Home.java:83)
        at com.example.clusterdroid.Home.onActivityResult(Home.java:72)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7472)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4590)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4639)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
Process 21383 terminated.
```

Comment: Prueba a verificar que la ruta `/storage/emulated/0/HeartDisease.csv` es correcta, un saludo.

Comment: esa ruta puede no existir en todos los dispositivos, se tiene que usar un método del.SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando obtienes el error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/HeartDisease.csv
>   (No such file or directory)

se debe a dos causas:

1) No tienes aceptado el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

2) La ruta o el archivo no existe.

En este caso al parecer no existe la ruta, 
tienes que obtener la ruta de esta forma y usar un método para leer la información:

```
...
...
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    readFile(uri);
                }
...
...
```

el método para leer la informacíón sería:

```
private void readFile(Uri uri) {}
        InputStream inputStream;
        File file = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
            file = new File(uri.toString());
  viewPath.setText(file.getAbsolutePath() + " is selected ");
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        } else {
            inputStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // do something with line from file
         viewInfo.setText(viewInfo.getText().toString() + line);
        }
        br.close();
    }
```

Comment: Funciono, gracias. ¿Es necesario que incluya los permisos de escritura en el Manifest (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)? me quede con esa duda ya que solo estoy incluyendo los de lectura (READ_EXGTERNAL_STORAGE)

Comment: Es necesario agregar en el manifest.xml WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  tanto para lectura como para escritura.